# Using enum value in rowfilter - DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, enums

I've managed to get a enum values to display in the dataviewgrid but I can't use the enum values in a rowfilter.

The rowfilter is built by the user so it must be in friendly format (i.e user wont know the enum ID).

Heres a stripped down version of the code that illustrates what I'm trying to do.  Bear in mind that I'm setting the rowfilter in the code here but the user will normally create the rowfilter.  The real rowfilter can be a lot more complex than the example.

Is there anyway I can "lookup" the enum id based on the supplied value?
The other option is to convert to using a string and set the LogType.ToString() in every row.  In some cases the datatable will contain over 400,000+ rows so I'm try be a lean as possible.

```
public enum LogType
{
    Log1,
    Log2,
    Log3,
    Log4
}

DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();

DataColumn rowIdColumn = new DataColumn();
rowIdColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
rowIdColumn.AutoIncrement = true;
rowIdColumn.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
rowIdColumn.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
rowIdColumn.ColumnName = "Row";

dtResult.Columns.Add(rowIdColumn);
dtResult.Columns.Add("File", typeof(string));
dtResult.Columns.Add("LogType", typeof(LogType));
dtResult.Columns.Add("Message", typeof(string));

//Parsing code **

while(gp.Read()){        //Parse log file

    switch (LogTypeValue)
    {
        case LogType.Log1:
            dtResult.Rows.Add(filePath, LogTypeValue, 'Test1');
            break;
        case LogType.Log2:
            dtResult.Rows.Add(filePath, LogTypeValue, 'Test2');
            break;
        case LogType.Log3:
        case LogType.Log4:
            dtResult.Rows.Add(filePath, LogTypeValue, 'Test3');
            break;
    }    
}
```

Results

```
string filter == "LogType = '2'";    //Returns correct data
DataView dtSearch = new DataView(dtResult, filter,"File",DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);       

string filter == "LogType = 'Log1'";    //Doesn't return anything
DataView dtSearch = new DataView(dtResult, filter,"File",DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

Answer (score 1):

enumeration is remembered as a number in the database, not as a string. You can try this:

```
string filter = "LogType = " + LogType.Log1;
```

Comment: This works however as I said the user creates rowfilter.  The rowfiler might be something like "LogType IN ('Log1', 'Log2')' AND Message LIKE '%Test%'".  This is built in a textbox so I can't see how I convert the LogType to the enum id.

Comment: If user is inserting LogType as a string, I don't see the point to use enum. Just simply use string value

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I would think using a enum would use less memory than writing the same value multiple times?

Comment: In your case it doesn't matter because your enum is type of int(32 bites) and 4 letter word is 4x8=32. But you can make your enum as Byte which will take less memory. And you can also create a method to convert the filter: switch(filter){case "Log1": int newfilter = 1; ...}